# PM2 starting Meteor App not working

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, meteor, digital-ocean, pm2

I have in one Digital Ocean Linux Ubuntu 16.041 droplet an instance of a Meteor app. Moreover, I installed Node.js version of 4.4.0

I created the respective bundle on the path `~/MyApplication/bundle`. As a matter of fact, I automated with a config.json file the execution which its body contains the following code:

[image: config.json]

My main.js file is created from the Meteor build `--directory ~/myDirectory/` command and contains the following code:

`process.argv.splice(2, 0, 'program.json');
process.chdir(require('path').join(__dirname, 'programs', 'server'));
require('./programs/server/boot.js');`

That being said, I run my application with pm2 through the config JSON file with `pm2 start config.json`

It starts the application, but several ms afterwards it is errored. The log error show the following exception regarding the typo, but seems the mainjs file is created fine. Any suggestions to solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I had to update the node version in the server from 4.4.0 to 8.9.1. After doing that changes, I also had to install the dependencies within the bundle/programs/server/ using `npm install`